# How to access the attributes within this JSON string in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

So I have this array that saves a json string.

```
Array
(
    [0] => "2jDQoU9D2wu04wqkg0ImUI":{"date":"2016-08-02 14:08:49","type":"story","story_id":"2jDQoU9D2wu04wqkg0ImUI","series_id":"1RAv0uDbcIieYgYqywqYmk"}
)
```

I want to be able to access just the value "2jDQoU9D2wu04wqkg0ImUI" at the start of the json string and then also be able to do something like `$value[0]['type']` to get the type from this json string object. I'm pretty new to PHP and struggling to get this working. I've tried JSON encoding/decoding and can't seem to get anything to work.

What's the proper way to go about this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this code will solve your problem.

```
$array[0] = '"2jDQoU9D2wu04wqkg0ImUI":{"date":"2016-08-02 14:08:49","type":"story","story_id":"2jDQoU9D2wu04wqkg0ImUI","series_id":"1RAv0uDbcIieYgYqywqYmk"}';

//print_r($arr);

$JsonString = '{' . $array[0] . '}';

$json = json_decode($JsonString);

foreach($json as $key => $value){
   echo "Key : $key <br />";
   echo "Type : ". $value->type."<br />";
   echo "date : ". $value->date."<br />";
   echo "story_id : ". $value->story_id."<br />";
   echo "series_id : ". $value->series_id."<br />";
}
```

Comment: Oh man thanks for this. No wonder nothing was working if the JSON was formatted incorrectly. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

so you have array $jsonArray and you want to access just the key of it

if its single dimension array :

```
  echo key($jsonArray); //prints 2jDQoU9D2wu04wqkg0ImUI
```

Otherwise if its multidimensional you can loop through it and do whatever you want with each key

```
foreach($jsonArray as $key => $value) {
    echo $key; //prints 2jDQoU9D2wu04wqkg0ImUI
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
$arrayOfObjects = [];    
 foreach($array as $key => $value)  arrayOfObjects[] = json_decode($value);
```

Now you can loop through this new `$arrayOfObjects`

```
foreach($arrayOfObjects as $key => $object){
    echo $object->date . '<br>';
    echo $object->type . '<br>';
    echo $object->story_id . '<br>';
    echo $object->series_id . '<br> ==== >br> ';
}
```